# MD Plot with Glimma starting from DESeq2 results

Tags: r

I'm trying to visualize results from the DESeq2 pepeline in interactive html, useing Glimma.

I read the vignette at "glMDPlot.DESeqResults" but I can't understand where to find the "counts", "anno" and "groups" arguments in the DESeqResults object (I made the DESeqDataSet starting from a FeatureCounts matrix of count and a .csv table for metadata). All the MDPlots examples I found so far can call arguments from SummarizeExperiment... but the Glimma vignette's claimig it's possible to start from DESeq2 too. I'm sure I'm missing something easy, but someone might can give me an example of this MD visualization of DESeq2 results, starting from a featurecount matrix and table of metadata?

Here following the code from the Glimma vignette:

```
**# S3 method for class DESeqResults**
glMDPlot(x, counts, anno, groups, ....)
**Arguments**
x = the DESeqResults object.
counts = the matrix of expression values, with samples in columns.
anno = the data.frame containing gene annotations.
groups = the factor containing experimental groups of the samples.
.....
```

I was thinking that x=res, counts= the countdata and anno= the datatable(coldata) used to build the (dds) DESeq2 dataset..but that isn't working..

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate the genes, and provide that column/data frame as the input. For groups that you'll know according to your experiments if samples belonged to the same group or not. You might want to look at some pipelines for RNA seq to get help, there are a lot of resources such as rafa lab, grifith lab bioconductor tutorials etc.